# Cannot Update nor Delete in SQLite on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

This is the code that I use

```
    dbhelper mydb;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    final Intent profile = getIntent();
    final String user = profile.getExtras().getString("tete");


    final EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pusername);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ppassword);

    username.setText(user);
    username.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); //Supaya username tidak dapat diganti

    Button update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btupdate);
    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newpassword = password.getText().toString();
            String newusername = username.getText().toString();

            if (password.getText().toString().trim().length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Baru Harus diisi minimal 6 karakter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                  mydb.editData(newusername, newpassword);

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "berhasil!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        }


    });
```

This is my code for the dbhelper class

```
 public void editData(String username,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1,username);
    contentValues.put(COL_2,password);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"USERNAME = ?", new String[]{username});

    //String query="UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL_2 + " = '" + password + "' Where " + COL_1 + " = '" + username + "'";
    //db.execSQL(query);



}
```

The logcat gave this error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.example.charlie.gate.dbhelper.editData(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

I tried to toast the newusername and the newpassword string to test if it were null and the result were both contain the value as intended, but somehow everytime I click the button the app forced close, Please help

Comment: How do you initialize mydb?

Comment: I edited the post, please check it out

Comment: holy god you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not initialize `mydb` correctly so it is null when you try to use it.  
Inside `onCreate()` add this line:

```
mydb = new dbhelper(this, ...);
```

usually you pass `this` and other parameters for this initialization.